# Get user response of clipboard prompt for document.execCommand

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I need to copy text in clipboard in JS by using `document.execCommand('copy');`.
In modern browser it work well and in IE11 there is a prompt.

How can i have the user response of this prompt ??

I have tried this code, but it returns always `true`....

**HTML :**

```
<textarea id="test">totototototot</textarea>
<button id='btn'>copy</button>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  var area = document.getElementById('test');
  area.setSelectionRange(0, $(area).text().length);
  var succeed = false;
  try{
    succeed = document.execCommand('copy');
  }catch(e){
    succeed = false;
  }
  alert(succeed);
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q535ycse/6/)

Anyone have an idea ? :)

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to check whether the clipboard contains the expected text. If you haven't got access to check the text, you haven't got access to set the text either. If you have got access, you can check it contains what you expect.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var area = document.getElementById('test');
    area.setSelectionRange(0, $(area).text().length);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    var expectedText = $(area).text();
    var clipboard = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    if(clipboard && clipboard == expectedText){
        alert(':)');
    } else {
        alert(':(');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/q535ycse/8/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! ^^